# Does expected value of square of a random variable always exist?

Tags: expected-value

Can we verify if $E(X^2)$ also exist, provided that E(X) exists?

Thanks.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=infinite+variance+finite+mean

Answer (score 0):

No, only the other direction is valid due to Jensen's inequality.